# xml document into data.frame in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I got a problem. I have an xml document and I need it into a data.frame in R.
so far I managed it to upload a simple xml into a data.frame using the packages `xml` and `plyr` and doing

```
dataframe=ldply(xmlToList("file.xml"), data.frame)
```

but when I run this xml:

```
    <BusinessUnitList>
    <BusinessUnit id="000000195">
      <User id="897654322" firstName="Rick" lastName="Test" middleName="R" defaultLanguageName="English">
        <RoleList>
          <Role id="worker"/>
        </RoleList>
        <OrgList>
          <Organization id="1111"/>
        </OrgList>
        <Address country="Italy"/>
        <Employee badgeNumber="575757" Date="2017-01-01" DateNew="2017-01-02" birthDate="1999-01-01">
          <Availability val1="5" val2="n" val3="6" HoursPerWeek="33.75" HoursBetweenShifts="10" minHoursPerWeek="00.00"/>
        </Employee>
      </User>
</BusinessUnit>
    <BusinessUnit id="000000111">
      <User id="897652222" firstName="TERI" lastName="tst2" middleName="D" defaultLanguageName="English">
        <RoleList>
          <Role id="worker"/>
        </RoleList>
        <OrgList>
          <Organization id="2222"/>
        </OrgList>
        <Address country="Portugal"/>
        <Employee badgeNumber="575757" Date="2017-02-02" DateNew="2017-02-02" birthDate="1998-01-01">
          <Availability val1="5" val2="n" val3="6" HoursPerWeek="33.75" HoursBetweenShifts="10" minHoursPerWeek="00.00"/>
        </Employee>
      </User>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </BusinessUnitList>
```

i receive an error: `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 7.`

Comment: Please provide sample data and code.

Comment: To be able to help you, we would need to understand what do you expect for the format of the output (which info do you want in which column?)

Comment: It's unlikely `[xml][1]` is in the actual XML file. You should take some time to understand the error (at least one column doesn't have the same number of entries). You likely need to actually do work as is often the case with XML files. There are scads of XML handling Q&A's on SO. You seem to have done absolutely no research.

Comment: @hrbrmstr that is an error when i wrote the example, i will fix it

Comment: @sinQueso i need the columns: (BusinessUnit) ID, (User)ID, firstname, lastname, middlename, defaultLanguageName, RoleID, organization ID, country, badgeNumber, Date, Datenew, birthDate, val1 val2, val3, HoursPerWeek, HoursBetweenShifts, minHoursPerWeek

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine a list like this

```
list(a=1:2, b=3:5)
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 3 4 5

data.frame( list(a=1:2, b=3:5))
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3
```

I would maybe unlist the `xmlToList` results and format the column names.

```
doc <- xmlParse("file.xml") 
x <- data.frame( t( unlist(xmlToList(doc))) )
names(x) <- gsub("(..attrs)?.id$", "_id", names(x))
names(x) <-  gsub(".*\\.", "", names(x))

  Role_id Organization_id country val1 val2 val3 HoursPerWeek HoursBetweenShifts minHoursPerWeek badgeNumber       Date    DateNew  birthDate   User_id firstName lastName middleName defaultLanguageName BusinessUnit_id
1  worker            1111   Italy    5    n    6        33.75                 10           00.00      575757 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 1999-01-01 897654322      Rick     Test          R             English       000000195
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your time. I was able to run the example and it's working OK, it formats the data I expected but when I add a second child the output in data frame only shows one record (the last one) and I'll have more records. The funny thing is that if I print the "x" object the console print my two records so I don't understand why this behaviour.  Also at some point I'm missing data, I'll update the XML so you can get my point.